# Do I have to clear a C++ vector after declaration?

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

Assume I declare a vector:

```
std::vector <int> v;
```

After this declaration, is it guaranteed that the vector is empty or do I have to explicitly clear/initialize it? Is calling `v.clear()` after the declaration useless or recommended?

Comment: I did not downvote, but I suspect people who did considered that the answer can easily be found in the documentation of `std::vector`'s constructor. For instance, on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), item #1 on the page.

Comment: On the one hand your question is valid, because for example non-class variables are not initialized to a particular value on the other hand it could be easily solved by doing some research beforehand. On the other other hand I too miss such obvious information all to often.

Comment: This is a good question. Of course it is a beginner question, but beginners naturally have trouble finding the right place to look at in the docs. So the lesson to learn here is: 1. Non-POD objects are initialized by the constructor, so look into its documentation. 2. Non-POD objects, like `struct {vector<int> v;} s;` may have a compiler-generated constructor only. 3. POD objects are not initialized with the above syntax, but no stl-containers are POD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When defining a variable like that, the default constructor is called. In `vector`'s case, the default constructor creates an empty vector with no elements, so no, you don't need to explicitly clear it.